# Two independent events affect probability of third event: find CI for third event

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability, model, excel

I know the title is vague: I couldn't think of a good one.

The basic question can be worded several different ways, but here is how I think of it to make it easier for myself:

> Sally has only one umbrella. Every morning there is 50% chance of rain, and every evening there is 50% chance of rain. Sally goes to and from school every day, and if it's not raining she will not take her umbrella with her. How many times does she have to walk in the rain without her umbrella?

So the way I'm going about this is to generate an Excel model that tests at least 30 samples, with each sample having 30 back and forth trips, using some formula to determine whether or not that trip is made without an umbrella even if it's raining. I've noticed that whenever it rains (let this be 1), if the total previous number of 0s (trips where it doesn't rain) up to the previous 1 is odd, then Sally is screwed. For example: if we have 1 0 0 0 0 1, meaning that it rained on the first trip and the last trip, Sally is okay because the number of 0's (4) is even. If it's 1 then 1, the second 1 is 1 because I treat 0 as an even number.

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to put this in some sort of Excel model. For example, I can have a column "# previous zeros," but how would I reset the formula once it hits a 1 in the other column? Also, how would I then proceed to take my results and probably construct a CI and five point summary in Excel? Thanks.

Comment: You need a correlation between a chance of rain in the morning and evening to do anything about this problem. It's not reasonable to assume that they're not correlated.

Comment: A CI and "five point summary" are procedures applied to *data*, which seems irrelevant to this question.  The question itself is unanswerable as stated because we are not told how many days Sally goes to school.  The reference to "at least 30 samples" is still too vague and seems to refer to a speculative solution method rather than the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this question analytically. Denote
$P(R_m)=0.5$ as the probability that it will rain in the morning, $P(R_e)=0.5$ as the probability that it will rain in the evening and $P(U)$ as the probability sally brought her umbrella to school. You are interested in figuring out $P(\bar{U}, R_e)$, i.e. the probability that she has no umbrella and it rains in the evening. Because these events are independent, $$P(\bar{U}, R_e) = P(\bar{U})P(R_e)$$

Now, $P(\bar{U}) = 1 - P(U)$, so we need to calculate $P(U) = P(U|R_m)P(R_m) + P(U|\bar{R_m})P(\bar{R_m})$. 
We know that $P(U|\bar{R_m}) = 0$ but don't know $P(U|R_m)$. Let's call it $p$ (it would be one if sally always remembers to bring her umbrella if it rains in the morning, but maybe she forgets sometimes). That means the probability for sally to walk in the rain is $(1 - P(U))\times P(R_e) = (1 - p\times P(R_m))P(R_e) = 0.5 -p*0.25$

If sally goes to school $N$ days, she will walk in the rain $N\times (0.5 -p*0.25)$ times